# Plot absolute coordinates / Image map

Tags: fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype, image

I have a site where I want to set up a "tour" of a software screenshot, and I need to allow users to select points on an image to insert the tour "stops". Is there an add-on like DevDemon's [Entry Mapper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-mapper) for Craft? Or does anyone have a suggestion for a way to do this that doesn't involve explaining to a client how to figure out coordinates on an image and then entering them into a Matrix field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Iain Urquhart's plugin, Pointy: https://github.com/iainurquhart/Craft-Pointy

It's a port of his EE addon that's similar to Entry Mapper, but I'm not 100% certain if it's production ready or not.